# How to sort inner array elements while maintaining different sorting for outer documents?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, mongodb-3.6

I have a collection of documents each of which has an embedded array.
I need the elements of each array to be sorted within themselves, while the containing documents should remain ordered as they are.

As an exemplification, taking the data from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15654228/3127111) on sorting:

```
[
    {
        name: 'item1',
        slots: [
            { date : ISODate("2013-01-18T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-02-05T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-24T23:00:00Z") },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item2',
        slots: [
            { date : ISODate("2013-01-12T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-01-03T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-04T23:00:00Z") },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item3',
        slots: [
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-14T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-02-18T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-07T23:00:00Z") },
        ]
    }
]
```

My expected result is slightly different:

```
[
    {
        name: 'item3',
        slots: [
            { date : ISODate("2013-02-18T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-07T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-14T23:00:00Z") },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item2',
        slots: [
            { date : ISODate("2013-01-03T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-01-12T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-04T23:00:00Z") },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item1',
        slots: [
            { date : ISODate("2013-01-18T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-02-05T23:00:00Z") },
            { date : ISODate("2013-03-24T23:00:00Z") },
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this in MongoDB 3.6? I'd like to use the aggregation pipeline, if possible.

I didn't try much so far, since the only stage I can think would fit for this is the `$sort`, but as stated [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort), it will sort the outer collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation query.

`$unwind` the `slots` array followed by sorting the docs date asc and `$group` back on `_id` to get the sorted array.

`$sort` on `name` desc to sort the documents.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$slots"},
  {"$sort":{"slots.date":1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","name":{"$first":"$name"},"slots":{"$push":"$slots"}}},
  {"$sort":{"name":-1}},
])
```